# Play Framework 1.2.4 Sync Jobs in an Async Thread: Possible?

Tags: ajax, multithreading, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-1.x

i am working on a project that is heavily relies on ajax requests on the main user page.

In the current web page, i have a "n" number of same views that have ajax request of each. so when the use load the page, there are "n" number of ajax requests runs at the same time.

also there is another design problem that, after the first request runs, the other requests will gather the data from tha cache. Heres the workflow:

Request:

1. Send Request
2. Check if cache has the required values
3. If not available, then gather the data from the webserver (which
   takes some time)
4. Gather the data, write the values for "x" minutes to the cache.
5. return the value
   .

So if i can manage to run just one request at the begining and let other requests wait for the first one to finish, they will be able to use the data available on the cache and it will greatly improve the performance.

The problem is play run all the jobs async so event those requests wont see a cache value at the first page load..

So what i need to do is this:

```
----Main ASYNC Thread------
-------first View Request----
-------second Request (it will run after the first one so it will read from the cache---
----- and so on...
```

so, How can i put requests in queue or how can i make other requests "await" is it possible?

I know i should have designed the applicaton for this but page design and javascript designs came from an outer source. so i dont have time to work on those things..

Thanks for helping..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encapsulate data loading logic in one method, you can sync all threads in that method, eg. using an AtomicBoolean flag.

```
private final AtomicBoolean initialised = new AtomicBoolean(false);

public Data getData() {
   Data data = null;
   if (!initialised.get() && initialised.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
     cache.put(loadData());
   }
   while ((data = cache.get()) == null);
   return data;
}
```

Just one of the approaches.

Comment: i've solved this problem by two approaches, first i realized that there is something called jquery.queue, so i am able to queue the ajax requests, and then i changed the logic in to something that calculates and cached the required values on the first request and others just look at the cached values. (logic is like "Look for cache" if not found "Look for DB" if not found "Performs calculation") with help of queue first one cached and the others get data from the cache.

Comment: BTW AtomicBoolean is just above my level of knowledge, thanks for sharing this informtion, i am accepting your answer becouse i also somehow encapsulated the data loading logic just like you said.. thanks

Comment: Np. Though, if the data you cache is shared between multiple users/sessions, or, say, similar requests are sent from two different tabs in a browser (session is same in this case), you will still have your initial problem. This is because there will be multiple jqery queues created for each page loaded. So some synchronisation mechanism on the server side may be essential to solving your problem.

Comment: thanks for the information, i've updated my application so that only one job is responsible for calculations, and i've isolated the other controllers from the calculation job. Also i've added a Model for job to look if there is another thread running the required job, etc.. its really hard to work with async jobs in generals imo.